# PHP: Use every line from txt to do this?

Tags: php, while-loop, line

Trying to write a script that gets a line from txt (line is url), goes to the url, searches and grabs specific data. Grabbing the data works, but i need to do this multiple times. This is the find and get snippet it works fine.

```
    include(dom.txt);
    $html = file_get_html('url here');
    foreach($html->find('a.live') as $e)
    echo (''.$e->innertext.'<br />');
```

Heres what ive done so far but i get an error "Warning: file_get_contents(Array)"

```
    <?php
    include ("dom.php");
    $file = fopen("urls.txt", "r");
    $i = 0;
    while (!feof($file)) {
    $line[] = fgets($file);
    }
    fclose($file);
    foreach ($line as $x){
    $html = file_get_html("$line");
    foreach($html->find('a.live') as $e)
    echo (''.$e->innertext.'<br />');
    }
    ?>
```

Could somebody help ? :(

Edit changed $html = file_get_html("$line"); with $html = file_get_html("$x"); but still get error

Edit 2 script works but i think it overwrites the results and is displaying only the last result

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the array `$line` into the function `file_get_html`, which only accepts strings.

You do have the foreach loop set to loop through the array. Use `file_get_html($x)` instead.

Comment: Thanks buddy edited that but still get an error   Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/a6180322/public_html/dom.php on line 151

Comment: Can you try doing a var_dump($line), to see if an element of the array is empty?

Comment: Add an `if (empty($x)) continue;` before your file_get_html line which will skip all empty lines in the file

Comment: fullybaked urls.txt has 2 test links the result has to be 1 url from the firs test link and 2 urls from the second test link. It works but displaying the results for the second test link. I think it overwrites it

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$html = file_get_html("$line");
```

should assumedly be:

```
$html = file_get_html("$x");
```

And as mastergalen has pointed out, there's no reason to include the `$x` in quotes. It doesn't gain you anything and just makes more work for the interpreter.

It's also worth noting that `fgets` will include a newline in the return value, which you may need to trim from the url before processing it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `file()` function which takes file path as argument and returns array of lines.

```
 <?php
 $aLines = file('/path/to/file');

 foreach( ( is_array( $aLines) ? $aLines : array() ) as $sLine )
 {
      // do what you have to do
      $html = file_get_html($sLine);
      foreach($html->find('a.live') as $e)
           echo (''.$e->innertext.'<br />');
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_get_html() (previously declared in /home/a6180322/public_html/dom.php:141) in /home/a6180322/public_html/dom.php on line 171

Comment: Your error comes from different part of your code - can you provide it?

Comment: You probably have following line `include('dom.php')` in file you include in some loop. You should change it to `require_once()` - the file will be included only once.